# Monaco Editor Code Completion with RESTful Webservice

Tags: jquery, typescript, promise, monaco-editor

I would like to implement a custom CompletionItemProvider for Monaco Editor 0.8.3, that is fetching completion suggestions from a RESTful webservice. For this, I would like to use jQuery 3.2.1.

- I have implemented a class implementing the `monaco.languages.CompletionItemProvider` interface.
- As calls to the webservice are asynchronous, I cannot directly return `CompletionItem[]` from the `provideCompletionItems()` method. Hence I guess I have to return a `monaco.Thenable<monaco.languages.CompletionItem[]>`-object.
- Unfortunately [documentation regarding the use of `Thenable`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.thenable.html) is very sparse . I guess, `monaco.Promise` class is kind of default implementation for the `Thenable` interface. As I have found  [one example using this class](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/blob/master/sample-diff-editor/index.html), I gave it a shot...

Here is the relevant code (below is the full code)

```js
                return new monaco.Promise<monaco.languages.CompletionItem[]>(function (c, e, p) {
                    req = $.getJSON("/codeeditorapi/objectcompletions/" + objAndProp[0]);
                    req.done(function (data) {
                        console.log("objectcompletions c(data) with " + data);
                        c(data);
                    });
                    req.fail((data) => e(data));
                }, function () {
                    req.abort();
                });
```

And now the full code of the class

```js
class MMSObjectModelCompletionProvider implements monaco.languages.CompletionItemProvider
{

    private PVAN:string = "v";//PlantVariableAccessor Name
    public provideCompletionItems(model: monaco.editor.IReadOnlyModel, position: monaco.Position, token: monaco.CancellationToken): monaco.Thenable<monaco.languages.CompletionItem[]> | monaco.languages.CompletionItem[]{
        var line = model.getValueInRange({ startLineNumber: position.lineNumber, startColumn: 1, endLineNumber: position.lineNumber, endColumn: position.column });
        let pos = line.lastIndexOf(this.PVAN+".");
        if (pos < 0 || line.length < pos + this.PVAN.length+1) //+1 for the dot behind
        {
            return [];
        }

        let objAndProp: string[] = line.substr(pos + this.PVAN.length + 1).split(".");
        let ret: monaco.languages.CompletionItem[];
        var req: JQueryXHR;
        switch (objAndProp.length)
        {
            case 3:
                //Only append the value
                return [
                {
                    label: "Value",
                    kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Property,
                    detail: "Access Value of plant variable",
                },
                ];
            case 2:
                //objectname finished, search for property
                if (objAndProp[0].length == 0 || objAndProp[1].length == 0) return [];
                return new monaco.Promise<monaco.languages.CompletionItem[]>(function (c, e, p) {
                    req = $.getJSON("/codeeditorapi/propertycompletions/" + objAndProp[0] + "/" + objAndProp[1]);
                    req.done(function (data) {
                        console.log("propertycompletions c(data) with " + data);
                        c(data);
                    });
                    req.fail((data) => e(data));
                }, function () {
                    req.abort();
                });
            case 1:
                //search for object name
                if (objAndProp[0].length == 0) return [];
                return new monaco.Promise<monaco.languages.CompletionItem[]>(function (c, e, p) {
                    req = $.getJSON("/codeeditorapi/objectcompletions/" + objAndProp[0]);
                    req.done(function (data) {
                        console.log("objectcompletions c(data) with " + data);
                        c(data);
                    });
                    req.fail((data) => e(data));
                }, function () {
                    req.abort();
                });
            default: return [];
        }
    }
}
```

Well, the webservice gets called properly and return the expected array with CompletionItems. I can see the console.log output. However, the call `c(data)` raises somewhere deep in the library the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.S [as compareIgnoreCase] (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:33:4808)
at _ (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:74:21918)
at C (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:74:22403)
at Array.sort (native)
at http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:74:21249
at Object.g [as _notify] (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:5529)
at Object.enter (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:9107)
at n.Class.derive._creator._run (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:10935)
at n.Class.derive._creator._completed (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:10376)
at n.Class.define.cancel.then (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:12368)
at Object.S [as compareIgnoreCase] (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:33:4808)
at _ (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:74:21918)
at C (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:74:22403)
at Array.sort (native)
at http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:74:21249
at Object.g [as _notify] (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:5529)
at Object.enter (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:9107)
at n.Class.derive._creator._run (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:10935)
at n.Class.derive._creator._completed (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:10376)
at n.Class.define.cancel.then (http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:35:12368)
at http://localhost:58254/Scripts/monaco-editor-0.8.3/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js:33:25360
```

I have no clue, what to do now. Any help or hints are appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure you have objects and not a json string returned by the service? 
Also - what I am doing in the complete method is to assign the result to a variable that is global to the function and then return this variable. This seems to work, although I wrote the code a while ago and it doesn't seem correct to me (could have race conditions).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer, it looks like the `provideCompletionItems` method can just return a Promise with the expected value, and Monaco editor shows `Loading...` in the completion box until the promise resolves.

So for your case in particular, just return a Promise inside of which you fire your request to the web service.
Also, the `provideCompletionItems` method should return an object with a `suggestions` property with an array of your completions.
`return {  suggestions: [...] }`